# GAE memcache api not able to store memcache key and namespace as integer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, memcached

I created a basic python web application using flask framework and deploy it on google app engine. So I store the JSON data utilising GAE memcache API with key and namespace as integer type and locally it worked, but once I deployed the code to app engine it's throwing the error `at least one of key or namespace should be <type> string`. 
I change my memcache key and namespace to type string and it works. Can someone help me understand why it's supporting integer as a key and namespace locally and but once you deploy it fails. Is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe, sometimes the sandbox behaves little bit different

Answer (score 1):

From [google.appengine.api.memcache package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache):

> Any method that takes a ‘key’ argument will accept that key as a
>   string (unicode or not) or a tuple of (hash_value, string) where the
>   hash_value, normally used for sharding onto a memcache instance, is
>   instead ignored, as Google App Engine deals with the sharding
>   transparently. Keys in memcache are just bytes, without a specified
>   encoding. All such methods may raise TypeError if provided a bogus key
>   value and a ValueError if the key is too large.

The local development server only attempts to emulate the actual GAE infra. Some aspects of the functionality aren't emulated entirely, some aren't emulated at all - the one you mention is not the only one. It's always a good idea to double-check your assumptions in real deployments, at least now and then, especially when exploring new GAE capabilities, to prevent including faulty assumptions in your app's foundation which would require significant re-working later. Been there, done that :)